# A question about the extension of homomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a quotation of a book "C*-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations" P275

> Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Suppose $I\triangleleft A$ be a closed ideal. If the representation $I\hookrightarrow B(H)$ is a nondegenerate representation, then the map $I\hookrightarrow B(H)$ can be uniquely to a *-homomorphism $\pi: A\rightarrow B(H)$ by defining 
>   $$\pi(a)=lim ae_{n}$$
>   where $\{e_{n}\}\subset I$ is any approximate unit and the limit is taken in the strong operator topology (uniqueness of $\pi$ is again due to the fact that $I\subset B(H)$ is nondegenerate).

I have **two questions** about the "extension" above:

1. Why does the author take the limit in the strong operator topology, not in norm topology? I think if the author define the limit in norm topology, then it is easy to see that this homomorphism is an extension.
2. How to prove the uniqueness of $\pi$ here? Actually, I do not know why should we verify the uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The limit may not exist in the norm topology (for instance if $I = K(H)$ and $\{e_n\}$ is the usual collection of finite rank projections converging SOT to the identity). However, the SOT limit exists, since $\{e_n\}$ is SOT-convergent (being an increasing sequence of self-adjoint operators that are bounded above)
2. As for uniqueness, suppose $\varphi$ is any other extension, we need to check that
   $$
   \pi(a)y = \varphi(a)y
   $$
   for any $y$ in a dense subset of $H$. Since $I \subset B(H)$ is nondegenerate, the set
   $$
   \{x\xi : x\in I, \xi \in H\}
   $$
   is dense in $H$, and
   $$
   \pi(a)x\xi = \pi(ax)\xi = ax\xi = \varphi(ax)\xi = \varphi(a)x\xi
   $$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.